# How can you delete thin geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a geometry that has very thin parts on some parts of the model. How can I clean these up and smooth the edges.

I have tried selecting sharp edges with an angle of 175. This gets some but completely misses others and selects some edges that I don't want to delete.

Image of sharp edge select
[image: Image of sharp edge select]
Image of sharp edge select after cleanup
[image: Image of sharp edge select after cleanup]
Image of after dissolving vertices
[image: Image of after dissolving vertices]

I attempted the solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128175/clear-sharp-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) and reset the normals but that didn't help.

If anyone know of a better way to do this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: tbh if i am looking at your "general" geometry - maybe you should cleanup that mess anyway? "normally" quad faces are a good idea because the subdiv modifier works great with it

Comment: This isn't my geometry. I am just trying to clean it up. This is only on specific edges.